# Free memory counter in PerfMon

Tags: sql-server, memory, memory-manager

Just want to make sure I am understanding this correct. Say I have set my maximum server memory according to best practice. Now I see in the the PerfMon counter:

```
SQLServer: Memory Manager - Free memory
```

Many Gigabytes (of free memeory). Does this mean that I can increase my "max server memory (MB)" until e.g. only a few MB is left (i.e. the Free memory counter only shows a few MB)?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that I can increase my "max server memory (MB)" until e.g. only a few MB is left (i.e. the Free memory counter only shows a few MB)?

This means SQL Server isn't actively using however much memory the counter is specifying. Thus, it wouldn't make a difference to increase max server memory since what you have is still free memory. If anything, depending on your settings, it might make things worse.

If you want to know if you can up the SQL Server max memory, then you'd want to look at the overall system memory, not just SQL Server. Additionally, you may (which I wouldn't) have multiple instances of SQL Server on the same OSE (operating system environment) in which all bets are off.

Comment: Why would sql server not use the memory to cache even more data?

Comment: If you have 5 gb free and you give it 5 gb more, it isnt going to use the extra 5 gb as it hasnt used the 5 it already had.